# long value supplied as a duration to animate - AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

Oky i am supplying this variable to animate a sprite sheet in andengine.

```
 player.animate(new long[] { 100,100},0,2,false);
```

The first long parameter it takes is a long as you can see which defines the duration.

But i keep getting the error

```
01-09 18:32:14.910: E/AndroidRuntime(13483): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pFrameDurations must have the same length as pFirstTileIndex to pLastTileIndex.
```

I know what this error means, but i cant figure out what long durations it is looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 player.animate(new long[] { 100,100,100},0,2,false);
```

or

```
 player.animate(new long[] { 100,100},0,1,false);
```

depending on how many frames the animation has

Comment: what do the other parameters mean? 0 , 2 and false? How do you guys know what they do? I couldn't find documentation for that.

Comment: 0 and 2 are the first and the last index of frame you want to animate.